# Bootstrap - JQuery not filling div correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'll try to simplify this as much as I can:

I have a bunch of thumbnails on my site in ul->li

```
<div class="jumbotron">
  <ul class="row">
    <div id="liStyle">
      <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-4"><img class="img-responsive" src="patsaat/thumb p (1).jpg"/></li>
      <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-4"><img class="img-responsive" src="patsaat/thumb p (2).jpg"/></li>
      ...
      <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-4"><img class="img-responsive" src="patsaat/thumb p (212).jpg"/></li>
    </div>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Then I have a modal which is hidden on page load and pops up when a thumbnail is clicked

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">         
      <div id="testi2" class="modal-body">                

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And as I click the thumbnail, I want to  grab the full version of the image.

I have the pictures in a folder formatted like

> folder/thumb p (1).jpg => thumbnail
>
> folder/p (1).jpg  => full picture

So yeah, I want to  grab the full image and slam that on the modal. And I have this piece of sript to do it

```
$(document).ready( function(){        
  $('li img').on('click',function() {
    var src = ( $(this).attr('src') );
    var img = '<img src="' + ("patsaat/" + src.slice(14)) + '" class="img-responsive" />';
    alert(img);
    var index = $(this).parent('li').index();


    var html = "";
    html += img;  
    html += '<div style="height:25px;clear:both;display:block;">';
    html += '<a class="controls previous testii" href="' + (index) + '"> < Edellinen </a>';
    html += '<a id="right" class="controls next testii" href="'+ (index+2) + '"> Seuraava > </a>';
    html += '</div>';
    alert( html );

    $('#myModal').modal();
    $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
      $('#myModal .modal-body').html(html);
      //new code
      $('a.controls').trigger('click');
    })
    $('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function(){
      $('#myModal .modal-body').html('');
    });
  });
```

This is where it gets annoying. I'm trying to cut the "thumb" part out of the src, and at the moment I'm doing it by snipping the whole 14 first letters of src away (leaving just "p (1).jpg"), adding "patsaat/" to the beginning of that string which leaves me with String img which is "patsaat/p (1).jpg". Looks right, doesn't it?

Then it creates the String html and adds String img to it. After that, it adds the needed code to create a neat box with Previous and Next buttons. I even used alert(html) to check the result and it leaves me with this which looks correct:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qsnBw.jpg

and yet, it still fills the modal with the thumbnail instead of the full image! What am I not understanding here? And damn, this turned into a wall of text, sorry guys.

Comment: Are you sure the full size image is not equal to the thumbnail?

Comment: btw instead of the splice you could use str.replace('thumb ', '')

Comment: i couldn't find any errors on your code. are you sure you have the large pictures under the main folder?

Comment: your html is invalid. `div` can't be a direct child of  `ul`, only `li` can. You probably want `div#liStyle > ul.row > li.col-...`

Comment: I'd simply things, make it more semantic and have a fallback in case javascript  is disabled. Wrap your thumbnails in a link to the full sized image. Change your jQuery to target the links and use the `href` attribute of the `a` tag to populate your modal. Don't forget to retrun false to stop navigation to the image.

Comment: Also it is bad practice to have white space in paths etc, probably not the issue her but fixing that wont help. I'd be wary off () too. Id change your file names to `thumb-p-1.jpg` etc